# Attach Table to MS Forms

Tags: office-365, microsoft-forms, table

I am trying to create forms with table. I have couple question on MS Forms.

Is it possible to attach table or Create/add table in MS forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not straight forward table control available in Microsoft forms.

However, you can use **Likert** control which gives similar look like table:

[image]

**Reference**: [Use the Likert, a new survey question type in Microsoft Forms](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-forms-blog/use-the-likert-a-new-survey-question-type-in-microsoft-forms/ba-p/147201)

Comment: Thank you Ganesh, However the Likert i have tried but does not suit to the requirement. Is any other possibility like out of box concept or Client Side.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other out of the box control similar to table.